# How to generate a JWT for a request?

Tags: javascript, automation, jwt, request, authorization

I am writing a simple automation app and encountered some difficulty when I try to download a file.

The website is free and public, so I don't need to register in order to watch, search or download any files. But when I press the 'download' button in the browser, it send the GET request to an address that looks like this: `"BASE_URL/retrieve/FILE_NAME&&directStream=true&JWT=..."`

This is the [website](https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/63199073/ifw/docs?application=), if you're curious.

The JWT is dynamic and changes for every download. So my question is how to imitate this request programatically then?

Comment: `The website is free and public` Note that this does not mean they allow indisciminate headless requests to scrape content. Check their TOS.

Comment: With regard to the issue, monitor network traffic in your browser and replicate the request that generates the JWT before making the call to download content.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan it helped! I realised that when I press the download button, at first it sends the POST request to the server, which responds with a JWT, and then goes the second GET request that uses that JWT to download a file

Answer (score -1):

[JWT](https://jwt.io/) stands for **JSON Web Token**, that is, it is a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (Javascript object notation), encrypted in some manner.

So you will need to:

1. Find out how your particular JWT is being encrypted (maybe it's a simple base 64 encryption). If your intention is legitimate, then you can reach out to the owners of the site with this question.
2. Find out what the format of your JSON should be, what fields are expected there and make sure you generate proper values for them
3. Make changes on your code so it generates a valid JSON that matches the expectation, does the encryption and appends the result to your URL

Comment: I've not downvoted, but your answer is covering the process of creating/encoding JWTs. The OP is asking about how to retrieve a JWT from a third-party website.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your comment. It seems to me that the question is about imitating a request being sent programmatically, where the JWT is the changing element, so his program will send the requests to the site, but it does not work for him, because his JWT does not meet the requirements of the site. This was the reason as of why I have answered this. It's possible that I misunderstood the problem though.

Comment: *maybe it's a simple base 64 encryption* - base64 is not encryption. And JWTs are in most cases not encrypted but just signed.